# Timer Issues - Updating Display

Tags: java, swing, timer

Since my last question I've made my timer program more complex and I've run into another wall. **I can't seem to get the display of both timers to update.** They print just fine using println but if I use static variables, it gives the correct values but only in the Break timer, which makes sense. So, no matter what I do, **I can't seem to figure out how to get the Active timer to update when it should and the Break timer to update when it should.** Here are the relevant parts of my code.

Can you provide guidance on how to get the display to update for each as the timer increments?

This class is the functionality of the timer:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TaskTimer {

    private int seconds = 0;
    private int minutes = 0;
    private int hours = 0;
    private final int UNIT = 1000;
    private Timer timer;
    private String name;


    public TaskTimer(String name) {

        ActionListener go = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(count());

            }   
        };

        timer = new Timer(UNIT, go);    
    }


    public void begin() {
        if(ControlTimer.isStopped()) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            hours = 0;

        }
        timer.start();  
    }

    public void end() {
        timer.stop();   
    }

    public String count() {
        if(seconds < 59) {
            seconds++;
        } else if(minutes < 59) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
        } else {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }

        return (String.format("%02d", hours) + ":" 
        + String.format("%02d", minutes)  + ":" 
        + String.format("%02d", seconds));
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public void setSeconds(int s) {
        seconds = s;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int m) {
        minutes = m;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(int h) {
        hours = h;
    }

}
```

This one creates the panels to go into the window:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class TaskTimerPanel extends JPanel{

    String panelName;
    private static String timerValue;
    private JLabel timeDisplay;
    JLabel title;
    TaskTimer taskTimer;

    public TaskTimerPanel(String panelName) {

        // Get timer
        taskTimer = new TaskTimer(panelName);

        // Setup Panel
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // Add Title Label
        this.panelName = panelName;
        title = new JLabel(panelName);
        p.add(title);

        // Add Timer Display
        timerValue = "00:00:00";
        timeDisplay = new JLabel(timerValue);
        p.add(timeDisplay);

        // Add Formatting
        title.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        timeDisplay.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        timeDisplay.setOpaque(true);
        title.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        timeDisplay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(), 
            new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        timeDisplay.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 48);
        title.setFont(font);
        timeDisplay.setFont(font);
        p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(new EtchedBorder(),
             new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));

        // Add to JFrame
        add(p);
    }
    public JLabel getText() {
        return timeDisplay;
    }

    public void changeDisplay(String time) {
        getText().setText(time);
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ControlTimer {
    private static boolean stopped = true;
    private TaskTimerWindow t;

    public static boolean isStopped() {
        return stopped;
    }

    public void activeTime() {
        t.activeTimer.taskTimer.begin();
        t.breakTimer.taskTimer.end();
        stopped = false;
    }

    public void breakTime() {
        if(!stopped) {
            t.activeTimer.taskTimer.end();
            t.breakTimer.taskTimer.begin();
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        if(!stopped) {
            stopped = true;
            t.activeTimer.taskTimer.end();
            t.breakTimer.taskTimer.end();
        }
    }


    public ControlTimer() {
        t = new TaskTimerWindow();

        t.buttons.start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                activeTime();
            }
        });

        t.buttons.stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                reset();
            }
        });

        t.buttons.pause.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    breakTime();
            }
        });
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ControlTimer t = new ControlTimer();
        }
    }
```

I've omitted the window setup and the buttons classes because I don't think they're important for this question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Also, limit the amount of code where possible. thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where the issue is so I'm showing what I think may be relevant. Also, it's pretty straight forward. The GUI doesn't update when the timer does. That should be clear from my question.

Comment: Okay, you've got it a little backwards, rather the passing a reference of TaskTimerWindow to the Timer, set up a observer pattern which allows observers to register interest in been notified when something changes, technically, this means you only need one Timer, as it's going to trigger tick events. Allow the observer to determine what should occur when the timer ticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a step back for second, you seem to need...

- A "timer", which has a fixed duration and which needs to generate some kind of "tick" event to let observers know that it's updated
- Some kind of "list" of "timers" which can run them sequentially as each "timer" completes

What you want to be careful with, is not passing reference of objects to other objects which really have no responsibility changing them or interest in them.  Instead, you should consider using a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) of some kind that allows you to monitor changes to the objects in a decoupled way.

This is the ["single responsibility principle"](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html)

In this case, the `Timer` doesn't care about your UI, it cares about running at some interval, for a specified period of time, generating events when it "ticks" and when it completes, that's it.  It's not it's responsibility to update the UI or make any other decisions.

When ever you're faced with a problem, you should spent some time to break the problem down into manageable chunks - AKA top down decomposition.  This allows you to identify the aspects of the problems, who the relate together and what information you might need to share

## A task with a time limit...

Based on what I understand of your problem, you have some task which has a defined duration and which must provide notification of when

- It ticks
- Is completed

For me, I always start with some interfaces, these define the overall contract/expectations that I want to expose to the outside world (AKA code to interface, not implementation)

```
public interface TimedTask {
    public void addTimedTaskListener(TimedTaskListener listener);
    public void removeTimedTaskListener(TimedTaskListener listener);

    public void addTimedTaskTickListener(TimedTaskTickListener listener);
    public void removeTimedTaskTickListener(TimedTaskTickListener listener);

    public void start();
    public void stop();
    public void reset();
    public boolean isRunning();

    public Duration getRunDuration();
    public Duration getTotalDuration();
}

public class TimedTaskEvent extends EventObject {

    public enum State {
        RUNNING, PAUSED, COMPLETED
    }

    private State state;

    public TimedTaskEvent(Object source, State state) {
        super(source);
        this.state = state;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

}

public interface TimedTaskListener extends EventListener {
    public void taskStateChanged(TimedTaskEvent evt);
}

public interface TimedTaskTickListener extends EventListener {
    public void timedTaskTicked(TimedTaskEvent evt);
}
```

Okay, so there's a bit going on there. The `TimedTask` is some task which has a "duration" (`getRunDuration`) and a total running time (`getTotalDuration`) or the amount of time that the task has been running.

It provides two observers, a state changed to monitor the life cycle change, and a ticked notification to let observers know when the timer has updated itself.

It also provides some simple management functionality, `start`, `stop` and `reset`.  The following implementation allows the task to be "paused" and "resumed" (by calling `stop` and `start`), but that's just because I had the code to do it :P

Normally, I'd start with an `abstract` implementation and implement the most common functionality (in this, probably the event management), which allows future implementations to focus on the important aspects of their own implementation, but for the sake of brevity, I've gone straight to a default implementation

```
public class DefaultTimedTask implements TimedTask {

    private EventListenerList listenerList = new EventListenerList();

    private Timer timer;

    // How long the timer has been continuosuly running     
    private Duration totalDuration;
    // The time of the last tick
    private LocalDateTime tickTime;

    // How long the timer should run for
    private Duration runDuration;

    public DefaultTimedTask(Duration duration, int tickInterval) {
        runDuration = duration;
        totalDuration = Duration.ZERO;
        timer = new Timer(tickInterval, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (tickTime == null) {
                        tickTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                    }
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                    Duration tickDuration = Duration.between(tickTime, now);
                    totalDuration = totalDuration.plus(tickDuration);

                    fireTaskTimerTicked();

                    if (totalDuration.compareTo(runDuration) >= 0) {
                        timer.stop();
                        fireTaskTimerStartedChanged(TimedTaskEvent.State.COMPLETED);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        timer.stop();
        tickTime = null;
        totalDuration = Duration.ZERO;
    }

    public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
        if (paused && timer.isRunning()) {
            timer.stop();
            fireTaskTimerStartedChanged(TimedTaskEvent.State.PAUSED);
        } else if (!paused && !timer.isRunning()) {
            tickTime = null;
            timer.start();
            fireTaskTimerStartedChanged(TimedTaskEvent.State.RUNNING);
        }
    }

    protected void fireTaskTimerTicked() {
        TimedTaskTickListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(TimedTaskTickListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            TimedTaskEvent evt = new TimedTaskEvent(this, TimedTaskEvent.State.RUNNING);
            for (TimedTaskTickListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.timedTaskTicked(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void fireTaskTimerStartedChanged(TimedTaskEvent.State state) {
        TimedTaskListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(TimedTaskListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            TimedTaskEvent evt = new TimedTaskEvent(this, state);
            for (TimedTaskListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.taskStateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isPaused() {
        return !timer.isRunning();
    }

    @Override
    public void addTimedTaskListener(TimedTaskListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(TimedTaskListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTimedTaskListener(TimedTaskListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(TimedTaskListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTimedTaskTickListener(TimedTaskTickListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(TimedTaskTickListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeTimedTaskTickListener(TimedTaskTickListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(TimedTaskTickListener.class, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        setPaused(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        setPaused(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return timer.isRunning();
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getTotalDuration() {
        return totalDuration;
    }

    @Override
    public Duration getRunDuration() {
        return runDuration;
    }

}
```

Okay, so again, there's a lot going. This implementation relies on Java 8's new Time API to keep track of how long the timer has been running.  Rather than assuming that the `Timer` is accurate (because it's not), this implementation tracks the amount of time between each tick and then adds that to a `Duration`, which represents the "total running time" of the task.  This allows the implementation to be paused and restarted simply.

Once the timer has been running for at least the required duration, it will generate a `COMPLETED` state change and stop.

## Some way to manage it

Okay, this gets us to a start point.  The next problem is, you have a number of timed tasks which need to run sequentially, one after the other.  Now you could simply set up implementations which chained together, but that's adding additional responsibility to the timers, instead, I've opted to create a "manager" which can control the timers, monitor their states and when one completes, start the next one...

```
public class TaskList implements TimedTaskListener {

    private List<TimedTask> timers = new ArrayList<>(25);
    private boolean running = false;
    private TimedTask current;

    public void add(TimedTask timer) {
        timer.addTimedTaskListener(this);
        timers.add(timer);
    }

    public void remove(TimedTask timer) {
        timer.removeTimedTaskListener(this);
        timers.remove(timer);
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.start();
            running = true;
        } else {
            startNext();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.stop();
        }
        running = false;
    }

    protected void startNext() {
        if (!timers.isEmpty()) {
            current = timers.remove(0);
            current.start();
            running = true;
        } else {
            running = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void taskStateChanged(TimedTaskEvent evt) {
        switch (evt.getState()) {
            case COMPLETED:
                TimedTask timer = (TimedTask) evt.getSource();
                remove(timer);
                startNext();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Really, nothing special

## Putting it together...

Well, that's all fine and good, but how would you use it?

Basically, you would create a `TaskList`, you would as many instances of `TimedTask` as you need, making sure to register as a `TimedTaskListener` to get tick updates, so you can update the UI (or what ever else you need to do), add them to the `TaskList` and when you're ready, start it, for example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.EventListenerList;

public class TimerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTest();
    }

    public TimerTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("00:00:00.00");

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(label);
            DefaultTimedTask task = new DefaultTimedTask(Duration.ofMinutes(3), 100);
            task.addTimedTaskTickListener(new TimedTaskTickListener() {
                @Override
                public void timedTaskTicked(TimedTaskEvent evt) {
                    TimedTask task = (TimedTask) evt.getSource();
                    Duration duration = task.getTotalDuration();
                    label.setText(format(duration));
                }
            });

            TaskList taskList = new TaskList();
            taskList.add(task);
            taskList.start();
        }

        public String format(Duration duration) {
            long hours = duration.toHours();
            duration = duration.minusHours(hours);
            long minutes = duration.toMinutes();
            duration = duration.minusMinutes(minutes);
            long millis = duration.toMillis();
            double seconds = millis / 1000.0;

            return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02.02f", hours, minutes, seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

## Other things...

This is pretty simple overview of the idea, you'd probably also want to provide some kind of observer to the `TaskList` it can generate notifications when all the tasks are completed.

You'll also need to add some kind identifier to the `TimedTask` `interface`, something like a `name` or something else you can use, just so you know what's actually going and which timer is actually running

Answer (score 2):

I have not answered questions in the past as a fair-warning. I have tried to think of a good solution for you but it may not be very well worded. I'm hoping this may hold you over until a better qualified Stacker replies Here goes:

---

The best solution i can think of is using the Component Library from java. I am assuming this **displayed** timer is not part of the JDK, rather something you are creating from scratch. Since I have not taken the time to run your code since I assume trying this would be pointless without the file you omitted, this is probably a decent solution. With the Component object handling the String you wish to print out all that would need to be implemented is another timer in your JFrame class to handle how often the Component calls the repaint method. 
Best of luck, I hope this was at least a helpful nudge. Cheers

```
//Class Variable
private static YourTimerComponent timerComponent = new YourTimerComponent(); 

//Put everything below where you made the JFrame
static int delay = 1000; //Milliseconds

frame.add(timerComponent);

ActionListener refresh  = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        timerComponent.repaint();
    }
};
new Timer(delay, refresh).start();
```

Then you need to create the component that draws the string. You should also decide where you want this to show on your JFrame within the JFrame class.

Comment: *" I am assuming this timer is not part of the JDK"* - `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: Sorry, I will rephrase. I mean a timer that is displayable in the JFrame is not in the JDK (This is what you are trying to code..I think?). If you can get them to work as system.out.println() 's then you can rewrite this as a drawString in an JComponent to be updated based on an additional timer. This may not be the most sound solution but it is possible.